# Application won't launch in debug mode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio: it builds in Release mode instead of Debug, so I cannot reach my breakpoints.

Of course I've tried to change it in Project -> Properties, but it doesn't change anything, a Release version is generated and the combobox will select "Release (active)" by itself again

Comment: You should also see it in the main Toolbar. On the left of `► Start` you usually have these selectors (combos): Target Platform (`Any CPU` etc.) and Build configuration (`Debug`, `Release` etc.). Open the Configuration Manager to see what's in there. Maybe you have 2 different Projects and Dependencies. Look also under Project/Properties both Debug and Build panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Build" menu there is a "Configuration Manager..." item:

[image: Location of "Configuration Manager..." menu item.]

Edit the configurations so that the Debug build does not have the same settings as a Release build.